# get datetime from one table and store it in other one

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting date from one `table->row` and storing same date in another table but when i get the date from first table its formate is changed like `'2019-05-16T13:28:08.000Z'` which is wrong format to be store in second table

```
{
    build_Data = await query (`SELECT
                                  build_Date, 
                                  house,
                                  bench,
                                  unit_measure, 
                                  motherstock_id, 
                                  created_at
                              FROM tbl_builds 
                              WHERE id = ${req_params.build_id}`
                             );

    let build_date = build_Data[0].build_Date;
    let house = build_Data[0].house;
    let bench = build_Data[0].bench;
    let unit_measure = build_Data[0].unit_measure;
    let motherstock_id = build_Data[0].motherstock_id;
    let created_at = build_Data[0].created_at;
    console.log(created_at, build_date);


    result = await query(`
       INSERT INTO tbl_move_builds (
        build_date,
        action,
        house,
        bench, 
        unit_measure,
        pots_moved,
        pots_damaged,
        damage_reason,
        motherstock_id, 
        created_at
        ) VALUES (
        '${build_date}',
        '${req_data.action}',
        ${house},
        ${bench},
        ${unit_measure},
        ${req_data.pots_moved},
        '0',
        '0',
        ${motherstock_id},
        ${created_at}
      )
        `
    );
}
```

i want to get the correct datetime formate to be stored in other table

Comment: What have you tried? what format do you want the date to be in? Would help if you actually asked a question rather than just stating what you want.

Comment: remove ` '${build_date}'` and construct a new date with  ${new Date(build_date)}